# Generating a batch file with %* as a parameter

Tags: windows, batch-file, parameters

I have a tool written in dos/batch that generates other batch files as need...

works fine and is very useful...
basically the inner working is the is the same as doing

```
echo dir /s \windows\*.log > logs.cmd
```

this make a script named "logs" with some functionality
(it's a simplification just to illustrate the objective)

recently I need to add %* as a parameter of the generated batch file
(to capture all the input parameters from a command line)

the problem is that I don't know how to generate the "%*" sequence

I try several escape sequences and tricks google(ed) from the net
but nothing seems to work

?any ideas??

Comment: What escape sequences have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) page, % marks must be escaped like this: `%%` (double percentage signs, so the second one will show up.

You should be able to pass in the `*` as a normal escape character, that is: `^%`. If that doesn't work, try `"*"` (but the ^ escape should work).

So together, passing in the `%*` param to your code would look like this: `%%^*`.

Comment: that is the problem... if you use that sequence in a "echo" it works... if you pass it as a parameter with a "call" it is expanded... even if it is escaped that way... ?any thoughts??

Comment: What do you mean by expanded?

Comment: in the sub-routine (or external .cmd) invoked by the call the parameters received is not the string "%*" but whatever parameters were passed to the .cmd that contains the call... thanks for your input anyway... just proves me that i was doing things right... they just do not work as they should...

Comment: think i need a guru,,, anybody knows how to bring Rob Van Der Woude to this question ? ;-) :-) !

Comment: your first suggestion works ok if I do not call a sub... or a external .cmd ... already tested several ways and to solve the problem I pass now a surrogate-parameter to be interpreted inside the script and replaced by %* ,,, with this circunvent I solved the problem.. but many thanks for your insight...

Comment: sorry i couldn't be of more help, but glad to hear that you found a workaround!

Answer (score 1):

Almost nothing to add to the jmoon's answer, but as it does not work for you (but works for me), you can try with something like

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    echo Current script arguments
    echo --------------------------------------------
    echo %*
    echo --------------------------------------------

    >"output.cmd" (
        echo @echo off
        echo echo %%*
        echo for %%%%a in (%%*^) do echo %%%%a
    )

    echo Generated file
    echo --------------------------------------------
    type output.cmd
    echo --------------------------------------------

    echo Pass different set of arguments
    echo --------------------------------------------
    call output.cmd 1 2 3 4 
    echo --------------------------------------------

    echo Pass our arguments
    echo --------------------------------------------
    call output.cmd %*
    echo --------------------------------------------

    echo Pass escaped string
    echo --------------------------------------------
    call output.cmd %%%%*
    echo --------------------------------------------
```

This will generate

```
W:\>input.cmd a b c d e
Current script arguments
--------------------------------------------
a b c d e
--------------------------------------------
Generated file
--------------------------------------------
@echo off
echo %*
for %%a in (%*) do echo %%a
--------------------------------------------
Pass different set of arguments
--------------------------------------------
1 2 3 4
1
2
3
4
--------------------------------------------
Pass our arguments
--------------------------------------------
a b c d e
a
b
c
d
e
--------------------------------------------
Pass escaped string
--------------------------------------------
%*
--------------------------------------------
W:\>
```

Comment: thanks... i was trying to avoid "enableextensions" "disabledelayedexpansion" as it conflicts with other configurations i use in batch files...

Comment: @ZEE, I include the `setlocal ...` line in almost all posted code,  declaring a environment where the test code works. In this case it is not required.